# Front End User Registration (sr_feuser_register): Required RSA auth backend not available

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I configured the plugin as far and now I wanted to look at them in the backend but get an error message:

Front End User Registration (sr_feuser_register): Required RSA auth backend not available.

Under Google I find no useful items.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps:

1) Check Dependencies or required extensions for [sr_feuser_register](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_feuser_register)

2) Check Conflicts extension, You have to disable or uninstall those extensions which is conflict with [sr_feuser_register](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_feuser_register)

3) Delete entire "typo3temp" folder

4) Clear install tool cache

Note: rsaauth extension is one of required extension for sr_feuser_register. If you are not able to login from FE, you can change FE=> "loginSecurityLevel" => 'normal' in your "LocalConfiguration.php" file.